# Compilation Fails on Ubuntu but Succeeds on Fedora for Project Using OpenSSL Functions

Tags: c, ubuntu, encryption, compilation, openssl

I am trying to compile the nwipe project from the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/Knogle/nwipe/tree/master. The compilation process completes successfully on a Fedora system, but fails on an Ubuntu machine with the same version of OpenSSL (greater than 3.0.2), which should support the necessary functions. Both systems have the libdev-ssl package correctly installed.

Here is a snippet of the compilation output on Fedora, where it compiles without errors:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -MT aes/aes_ctr_prng.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o aes/aes_ctr_prng.o aes/aes_ctr_prng.c &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
...
gcc -g -O2 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -lcrypto -o nwipe nwipe.o ... -lparted -lpthread -lpanel -lncurses -ltinfo -lconfig
```

However, on Ubuntu, I encounter linker errors related to OpenSSL functions `AES_set_encrypt_key` and `AES_encrypt`, which are marked as deprecated since OpenSSL 3.0 but are still included in the project:

```
/usr/bin/ld: aes/aes_ctr_prng.o: in function `aes_ctr_prng_init':
/tmp/nwipe/src/aes/aes_ctr_prng.c:22: undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
/usr/bin/ld: aes/aes_ctr_prng.o: in function `aes_ctr_prng_genrand_uint32':
/tmp/nwipe/src/aes/aes_ctr_prng.c:41: undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/nwipe/src/aes/aes_ctr_prng.c:41: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Given that the compilation succeeds on Fedora but fails on Ubuntu, despite having the same OpenSSL version and seemingly correct dependencies installed, what could be causing this issue? How can I resolve these linker errors on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

This link command ...

> ```
> gcc -g -O2 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -lcrypto -o nwipe nwipe.o ... -lparted -lpthread -lpanel -lncurses -ltinfo -lconfig
> ```

... places `-lcrypto` incorrectly on the command line.  It should follow all the object files (and any libraries) that call any of its functions.  It's unclear why the build nevertheless works on Fedora, but not at all surprising that it fails on Ubuntu.

I presume that the project's build system is responsible for that placement, not you, personally.  In that case, you're looking at a flaw that you should report to the project's development team.

Meanwhile, if you feel competent to do so then you could try to fix it yourself, but you have not presented enough information for us to fix it for you.

Comment: There are many different linkers in the Linux world and not all of them use the traditional "scan once and forget" method.

Comment: Sure, @n.m.couldbeanAI, but some of the major ones *do* use the traditional method, and many linkers in the broader world do, so if one wants to publish a project for others to build and run then one should provide a build system that will work broadly.  It's not like link command order is a place where that gets hard.  That leaves me happy with "places `-lcrypto` incorrectly".  It is undoubtedly incorrect for the OP's Ubuntu environment, where it does not work.

Comment: Right, you just shouldn't be surprised when an incorrect/non-traditional link line succeeds on a specific distro. It probably just uses a different linker.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your reply already!
As mentioned by yourself, the issue was somewhere in the placing of `-lcrypto`
What has solved the issue, was adding the dependency for the autoconf script, in `configure.ac` Added OpenSSL there, and now it compiles fine!
Thanks for your help though.

```
KG_CHECK_MODULES(
[OPENSSL],
[openssl],
[
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} ${OPENSSL_CFLAGS}"
        LIBS="${LIBS} ${OPENSSL_LIBS}"
],
[AC_CHECK_LIB([ssl], [SSL_library_init], [
        LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto $LIBS"
        AC_CHECK_HEADERS(openssl/ssl.h,, [
            AC_CHECK_HEADERS(openssl/crypto.h, [
                AC_DEFINE([OPENSSL_IN_SUBDIR], [openssl/], [Look for openssl headers in subdir])
                ], [AC_MSG_ERROR([openssl headers not found])])
        ])
    ], [AC_MSG_ERROR([OpenSSL development library not found])]
)]
```

)